# Want to add Placeholder to Dynamically Generated Field Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Reactive form in which the input fields are generated dynamically 
I want to change the placeholder of input fields which are dynamically generated 
based upon what user has selected in the first textbox.

So Suppose User typed anything in first textbox so based upon that i want to change the value of Second textbox and so on..

Please note all the input fields are dynamically generated so i cannot just update the placeholder like this:
somePlaceholder : string = "new value";

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm">
            <div formArrayName="products">
                <div *ngFor="let prd of products().controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div class=""> 

                        <mat-form-field  class="">
                            <input OnlyNumber="true" DecimalPlaces="3" (keyup)="ChangePlaceHolderValue(i)"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" maxlength="16"  matInput id="txtProdFees" name="txtProdFees" formControlName="txtProdFees" class="form-control">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="this.productFrmArray.controls[i].controls.txtProdFees.errors?.greaterthanzero">Value should be greater than {{minProdFees}}</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="this.productFrmArray.controls[i].controls.txtProdFees.errors?.maxError">Fees cannot be greater than {{maxProdFee}}</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="this.productFrmArray.controls[i].controls.txtProdFees.errors?.invalid">Fees should be greater than {{productFrmArray.controls[i].controls.txtProdFees.errors?.lowerfee}}</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: It would be nice to provide stackblitz. all I can say s far is "you can do it!" (:

Comment: Show us your template and the creation of the form group please.

Comment: i have added the HTML code so based upon what user types in the first textbox i want to change the placeholder values in the next textboxes and so on, so the placeholder variable cant be just one.

Answer (score 0):

just use a variable

```
<input matInput [placeholder]="variable">
//in ts
variable="Ex. pizza"
```

NOTE: `<mat-placeholder>` is deprecated